# pandas unexpected set_index behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [['g1','a',1],['g1','b',2],['g2','b',3],['g2','a',4]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['group','name','count'])
print df.set_index(['group','name'])
print df.set_index(['name','group'])

            count
group name       
g1    a         1
      b         2
g2    b         3
      a         4
            count
name group       
a    g1         1
b    g1         2
     g2         3
a    g2         4
```

This behavior is rather surprising to me because I was expecting the second output to be like

```
            count
name group       
a    g1         1
     g2         4
b    g1         2
     g2         3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DataFrame needs to be sorted first to get your desired output:

```
In [12]: df.sort_values('name').set_index(['name','group'])
Out[12]: 
            count
name group       
a    g1         1
     g2         4
b    g1         2
     g2         3
```

Comment: Indeed the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex) discuss why this is important

Comment: Link in the docs is now here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex